# Encontrar div que contém imagem e adicionar classe para reconhecimento do CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

Preciso de ajuda para encontrar as tags `<img>` que tem dentro da estrutura abaixo.

Quando encontrado, adicionar uma classe "hasimg" junto a classe "skuFiltro" da tag `<ul>` primária. Preciso reconhecer se tem imagem ou não para poder diferenciar o estilo CSS da estrutura de front-end de uma plataforma que estou trabalhando.

```html
<ul class="skuFiltro">
    <li>
        <ul class="filterBlock">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="/img/teste.img" alt="">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="skuFiltro">
    <li>
        <ul class="filterBlock">
            <li>
                <a href="#">380mm</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para percorrer todos os elementos com a classe 'skuFiltro', você pode utilizar:

```
$('.skuFiltro').each(function(index, element) {
    var img = element.querySelector("img");
    if(img != null){
       element.addClass("hasimg");
    }
});
```

A função [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) percorre cada elemento que possua a classe .skuFiltro. A [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) está verificando dentro do atual elemento do .each, se há alguma tag 'img', caso não tenha nenhuma dentro do elemento em questão, a variável img vai receber NULL.

Comment: Obrigado Vinicius, problema resolvido! :)

Comment: @IvanRichardRoncatto show! Caso minha resposta tenha contribuído para sua resolução, se puder marcar ela como "resposta".